# How to create a simple admin module grid for products in Magento?

Tags: magento, module, grid, admin

I'm creating a very simple admin module which displays a list of products and their stock levels, and I want to present the data in a nice Magento grid. Later I will make it a form which will allow the user to update the stock via this page.

I've created the ability to show an admin phtml page with the IndexController like this:

```
<?php
class Creare_StockManagement_IndexController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
   {
    public function indexAction()
   {
    $this->loadLayout();

    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/template')
    ->setTemplate('stockmanagement/list.phtml'));   

    $this->_setActiveMenu('stock_menu/stockmanagement');

    $this->renderLayout();
  }
}
```

My list.phtml page contains a basic table and product list that I have echoed using the collection. I've been reading tutorials on the Internet about how to use Magento's grid system, but probably being a bit out of my depth I'm struggling to complete the next stage.

Can anyone point me in the right direction in terms of what files I need? The Module name is StockManagement. I feel like I'm very close, I just lack the understanding at this stage to piece it all together.

Anyway, any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

When I last used it, [Module Creator](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/danieln/extension/1108/modulecreator) makes an admin page with a grid - although I haven't used it recently so am less sure what it currently does.

You won't need a template since the grid and grid container widgets already have flexible templates built in.

Comment: Yeah, I gave it a try but couldn't get past the 'Create Module' page due to a PHP error. I suspect it's not compatible with the latest versions of Mage...

Comment: Then I should go back and try it more often.

Comment: i have also a problem relating to this question.. I have create a module with module creator, now i need a tab in adding item form, which is a grid and where i can select multiple records, so what i can do to achieve this, either copy the already grid or create a template, would you like to explain it?

Comment: You need to add a [mass action](http://www.activoinc.com/blog/2009/10/08/magentos-massaction-for-custom-plugins/) to the grid. This makes one column into a list of checkboxes. It is fairly straightforward but is worth looking at a few example classes such as `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Customer_Grid` to see what tricks are available, eg. additional input fields for the grid-form.